# how to find out if sub keys exists for a registry key using power shell command

Tags: powershell, command-line, registry, execution, registrykey

how to find out if sub keys exists for a registry key using power shell command
the registry key is under:

```
HKLM\Software\Policies\mirosoft\windows\SrpV2\Dll
HKLM\Software\Policies\mirosoft\windows\SrpV2\Exe
HKLM\Software\Policies\mirosoft\windows\SrpV2\Msi
HKLM\Software\Policies\mirosoft\windows\SrpV2\Script
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

To test for existence of a path use the Test-Path cmdlet:

```
$path = 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\mirosoft\windows\SrpV2\Dll'
if (Test-Path $path) {
    "$path exists"
}
else {
    "$path doesn't exist"
}
```

Comment: You forgot the colon after HKLM, but I can't fix it because edits have to be >6 characters.